# Grafana OAuth with keyclock and flask

Tags: flask, single-sign-on, grafana

I am trying to make the Keyclock SSO work with the webapp and Grafana which is embedded in.

I have made the grafana integerate with the keyclock and I am able to login using the keyclock into grafana. But when I embed the grafana as inframe into the webapp, and log into the webapp with keyclock, am shown the error as

> login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state)

This is my flask config

```
{
    "web": {
       "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/realms/internal",
        "auth_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "flask",
        "client_secret": "nlY4o3kIrReiwwsYo0FrKFDHIZvfdXd5",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://localhost:5000/*"
        ],
        "token_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
        "userinfo_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
    }
}
```

Following is my grafana config

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
name = OAuth
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = grafana
client_secret = CA6OIr8z9v3ZPY4yhPWMSwZWJIPWaRK7
scopes = openid email profile
;email_attribute_name = admin@test.com
;email_attribute_path = admin@test.com
auth_url = http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://localhost:8080/realms/internal/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
;allowed_domains =
;team_ids =
;allowed_organizations =
role_attribute_path = "contains(roles[*], 'Admin') && 'Admin' || contains(roles[*], 'Editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'"
;tls_skip_verify_insecure = false
;tls_client_cert =
;tls_client_key =
;tls_client_ca =
```

I have the following settings for the cookies and embedding

```
cookie_samesite = lax
allow_embedding = true
```

I am getting an 500 Error auth to the grafana is redirected
[image]

Comment: Why `cookie_samesite = lax`?

Comment: You are so right about asking it, disabling the cookie_samesite fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SameSite=Lax:
> Only send the cookie in a first-party context (meaning the URL in the address bar matches the cookie domain). Do not send it with the following cross-origin requests: non-GET, AJAX, iframe, image requests etc. It saves the user from cross-site request forgery.

So `Lax` is blocking cookie "propagation" to iframe in your use case. `None` is better option in this case for `cookie_samesite` Grafana config.